# add the mean gray value of image with python

Tags: python, opencv

i want to add the gray mean value of image y to image X but i get this error :

> imgr=X+mean ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with
> shapes (299,299) (4,)

```
img = cv2.imread("X.png")
img = cv2.resize(img,(299, 299))
X   = img[:,:,1]

Y    = cv2.imread("Y.png")
mean = cv2.mean(Y)

imgr = X + mean`

cv2.imshow("AND", imgr)
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of `cv2.mean()` and check the value of `mean` using the debugger.

Comment: yes it's give me a mean value , how can i aad this value to image to get this formulae (img) + mean(img2)

Comment: I am getting an array of 4 elements (mean of each color channel, and one zero).

Comment: Use np.mean to get one value. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html